# Java Double Cannot Be Dereferenced

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I need to multiply `radius*radius*pi` to find exact area of the circle but the code I wrote down is not working. It is keep giving double cannot be dereferenced error...

ERROR

```
 ----jGRASP exec: javac -g Circle.java
Circle.java:7: error: double cannot be dereferenced
      BigDecimal area = radius.multiply(pi);
                              ^
1 error
```

CODE

```
import java.math.*;
public class Circle {
   public BigDecimal findArea(double radius){
      double pi = 3.14159;
      radius = radius * radius;
      BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("1");
      BigDecimal area = pi.multiply(radius);
      return area;
   }
}
```

Comment: Is that really the error for that code? Why would one say `radius.multiply(pi)`, and the other say `pi.multiply(radius)`?

Comment: However: Use `pi * radius` (or `radius * pi`). In both cases, they are primitive `double`, not `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Also: why define `double pi` instead of using `Math.PI`? And why `new BigDecimal("1")` instead of using `BigDecimal.ONE` ?

Comment: "to find exact area of the circle" Why do you think that `BigDecimal` helps you here? You're doing imprecise calculations as it is, since you're not using the exact value for π. Using `double` would suffice.

Comment: `double` is a primitive type, not an object, and you can't call `multiply()` on a primitive (in other words, you can not dereference it like you can dereference an object).

Answer (score 5):

Dereferencing does not work on primitive types. `double` is a primitive type.

Therefore

```
pi.multiply(radius)
```

is a invalid expression.

You could use something like this:

```
BigDecimal area = BigDecimal.valueOf(pi).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(radius));
```

or this

```
BigDecimal area = BigDecimal.valueOf(pi*radius);
```

instead.

Comment: Easier to read, fewer objects created: `BigDecimal area = BigDecimal.valueOf(pi * radius);`.

Comment: I might also point out that `radius = radius * radius;` a few lines above is confusing - simpler just to remove that line and write `pi * radius * radius` here.

Comment: The `pi * radius` approach will run much faster because of floating-point technology but will also give different results involving the inaccuracies of floating-point. So it depends on what the programmers wants: speed of execution with approximate results (the second example) or much slower but with more accurate results (the first example line).

Answer (score 2):

`pi` and `radius` are double primitive types, meaning they can't be dereferenced and you cannot use methods like `multiply`. Try this:

```
BigDecimal area = BigDecimal.valueOf(pi * radius);
```

Or:

```
BigDecimal area = BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.PI * radius);
```

In the example, I substituted `pi` with `Math.PI` as it's builtin to Java and more precise. The code above takes the value of `Math.PI * radius` and converts it into a `BigDecimal`.